# Xamarin forms SFListview multiselect issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Iam using syncfusion SFListview in my xamarin forms app. I implemented multiselect of listview cell from https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/selection?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xaml.It works fine.But the problem iam facing is everytime we need to hold the itemcell for selection. Is it possible for multiselect that hold only for first cell and tap for all other cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for multiselect that hold only for first cell and tap for all other cell?

**Sure can do that**.If you want multiselect items,I guess that next steps will do some tasks about multiselect items.The picture below may look like the one you want.

You can look at the content of [this chapter](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/selection?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xaml#show-checked-circle-on-selected-items) in the share link, and [the sample code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Checked_Circle_OnSelected_Items-1476673984?_ga=2.73909200.336410980.1551939205-24820431.1551939205) it provides.

**Solution One**:(Generally acceptable)

If the project doesn't mind adding a control button outside, then this will be the quickest and easiest way.That is to add a `ToolbarItems` in the `NavigationPage`, use it to control whether you can click multiple selections without jumping to the next page.

Add `ToolbarItems` :

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItemsButton" Text="MultipleSelect" Clicked="Edit_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<sync:SfListView x:Name="listView"
                 SelectionGesture="Hold"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"
                 SelectionBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 IsStickyHeader="True" ItemSize="70">
 ...
```

In `ContentPage` ,add Flag to judge `SelectionMode` of `ListView`.

```
int flag = 0;

private void Edit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(0 == flag)
    {
        listView.SelectionGesture = TouchGesture.Tap;
        ToolbarItemsButton.Text = "Done";
        flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ToolbarItemsButton.Text = "MultipleSelect";
        listView.SelectionGesture = TouchGesture.Hold;
        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Can judge when you can switch to the next page.

```
private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{

    if(0 == flag)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage());
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

**Solution Two**:(Recommended)

`SfListView` has a method is [ItemHolding](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms~Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView~ItemHolding_EV.html).Not using another button also can exchange the `SelectionMode`.

*Xaml* code different is adding this method of `SfListView`.

```
<sync:SfListView x:Name="listView"
                     SelectionGesture="Hold"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple"
                     ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"
                     SelectionBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                     ItemHolding="ListView_ItemHolding" // ItemHolding
                     IsStickyHeader="True" ItemSize="70">
```

When OnHolding can do something here:

```
private void ListView_ItemHolding(object sender, ItemHoldingEventArgs e)
{
    if (0 == flag)
    {
        listView.SelectionGesture = TouchGesture.Tap;
        ToolbarItemsButton.Text = "Done";
        flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        listView.SelectionGesture = TouchGesture.Hold;
        ToolbarItemsButton.Text = "MultipleSelect";
        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Judge when you can switch to the next page.

```
private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{

    if(0 == flag)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage());
    }

}
```

**Solution Three**:(Not recommended here)

Generally, for the multiple selection of the cell of the listview, we will process the template of the custom cell, such as adding a button in the template. When clicking, the item can be marked as selected, and the UI of the item can also be customized as The style when selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jiang. I implemented this. But the selectionimage will only shows whenever I hold the listview cell. I have other actions for taping the listview cell.So how can i add that circular selectionbutton? How can I implement that?

Comment: @AndroDevil Do you have a try with `SelectionMode="Multiple"` first?

Comment: Jiang I provided  ItemTapped="List_Tapped"
                           SelectionMode="Multiple"
                           SelectionGesture="Hold"                        The multiselection works fine. The problem is every time i should hold the cell for selection. I just want the multiselection to be work like when hold for first cell and tap for all other cell. Normal tap of listview will go to another screen in my case

Comment: Okey, I get it.You want hold one item,then every item show multiselect status,other items just need tap can be selected and not go to another page.In addition, I think that in this case, when you need to end the multi-select operation, it also needs a way to close multiple selections.Is that right?

Comment: jiang, Exactly bro!

Comment: OKey, the fast way is you can add a `ToolbarItem`(MultipleSelect) in `NavigationPage`.When you click it,`listView.SelectionGesture = TouchGesture.Tap;listView.SelectionMode = Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SelectionMode.Multiple;` .Now tap can not push to next page by mode.And when next clicking it,`listView.SelectionMode = Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SelectionMode.None;`I will update answer .

Comment: @AndroDevil Have updated.If be helpful,remember to mark it.Thanks!

Comment: @AndroDevil Updated the recommended Solution.Adding button here may not be the best way for `SfListView`.

Comment: Ok bro,,,,Let me check...Thanks for the help